# Selenium: Process unexpectedly closed with status 11

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Running this python script with selenium result in an error.

Python script:

```
"First selenium script"
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    service=FirefoxService(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Console output:

```
alex@nobara ~/selenium$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/selenium/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 177, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/alex/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 11
```

Geckodriver.log:

```
1666974769008   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:58881
1666974769634   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--remote-debugging-port" "56809" "--remote-allow-hosts" "localhost" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile6UjIeC"
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 6111
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
```

I'm currently on Linux (Nobara, fedora 36)

First i tried to move around the gecko driver (installed in /usr/local/bin) in home/selenium folder with the script, adding to GeckoDriverManager function a path parameter.
Same error appearing.
Then i tried: sudo chmod -R 777 ~/selenium/ (script path)
Then tried to refresh firefox: from about:support also disabling all extensions.

Comment: What version of selenium do you have?

Comment: selenium version is 4.5.0

Comment: The problem is only with the firefox? Does chrome work?

Comment: Just tried via Chrome, everything is working

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using chrome instead of firefox, everything is working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).